# Where can I get pre-trained weights for character recognition?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, cnn, pytorch

I'm doing a simple pipeline and I need a digit recognition algorithm. There are definitely pre-trained weights out there for character recognition, but I can't find them. They can be in Keras, Tensorflow, or Pytorch.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/hub is a good starting point

Comment: https://modelzoo.co/ - theres a few mnist models on there https://modelzoo.co/model/pytorch-playground